# ASP.NET/AJAX Modal

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want an animation modal (loading please wait) and when the page fully loads it disappears?

Comment: I want a lot of things, but I tend to do a little more work before coming on here...

Comment: yeah dood. Code would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$(function() { $('#loading').fadeOut(); });
```

The rest is CSS and an animated GIF.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, try something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var reqMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  reqMgr.add_beginRequest(ShowWait);
  reqMgr.add_endRequest(HideWait);
});

function ShowWait() { 
  $("#Loading").fadeIn();
}

function HideWait() { 
  $("#Loading").fadeOut();
}
```

Then just have an element:

```
<div id="Loading">Loading, Please Wait...</div>
```

Style and position as you want with css, default it to have a `display: none;` though.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write some simple html with your loading message (and may be a page mask to make it grayed) and place it at the beginning of the page. And at the end of page add script to remove that message and mask (see first answer). So users will see this message as soon as they get the html page (also some browsers support rendering of incomplete pages during loading of the page). See the code of [this page](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/) for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite way to make a modal popup. It does not use any AJAX, it's just pure HTML & CSS: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

You can hook it up to code-behind instead of using hyperlinks (get rid of the opacity attribute and work with div.visble = true/false). Set the modal div visible as default, then when page load completes, set it to visible=false.